# Unable to render KML file into google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, geoxml3

My Google map code

```
var myOptions = {
    center: {lat: 55.864237, lng: -4.251806},
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map1
});
var source = 'https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml';

geoXml.parse(source);
```

And the error i am getting is as follows:

Failed to load https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

XML parse error
Unable to retrieve https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml

Anyone knows how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Try downloading the kml file and loading it locally into your page. The error you are getting is due to a security restriction where google is blocking you from loading resources that reside on their server. [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 0):

[GeoXml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) uses the browser's XmlHttpRequest object, which is subject to the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access).  You can't access`https://developers.google.com` from `http://localhost:8080` (different origins).

To use GeoXml3, either copy that file to your server and access it through a relative URL or access it through a proxy on `http://localhost:8080`.

[example loading that URL through a proxy](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml)

[example using the `proxy` property of GeoXml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_proxy_linkto.html?filename=https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml)

Another option would be to use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 [`KmlLayer`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer), which accesses the KML from Google's servers and isn't subject to the same origin policy.

Comment: Actually I tried KML Layer at first and stuck up in following issue. 1. I have uploded my kml file on dropbox. And i successfully render that kml file in google map. But color schema and polygons with different colors were not displaying in map. It was just showing polylines. I came to know this issue when i uploaded this file on online KML viewer.(http://ivanrublev.me/kml/).  Link of my kml - https://www.dropbox.com/s/5fj8cns3nglcrcn/TRACKMAP.kml?dl=1    Thats why i was trying by another way.

Comment: The KML is not "mine", it is from Google (in the OP's question).  The polygons in the examples are filled with color.  Look closer at the style definitions.